How do I send the current selection to a desktop application in Wayland?
I use Pot Desktop to translate words.
I cannot use it with the content I selected Neovim by selecting text with the
mouse (Visual mode).
Tech stack:

kitty
wayland
hyprland
archlinuxcn


Please [edit] with details: what is the pot-app/pot-desktop word translation function (link?)? Do you need the OS to know about the selection in Neovim? What terminal or GUI are you running Neovim in? Are you selecting text with Visual mode or something else? I don't know if wayland support is complete yet, but :help x11-selection might give some advice?

I'm using this library https://github.com/pot-app/pot-desktop to select the translation function, but it doesn't work on nvim.I use a kitty terminal, the graphical interface is hyprland, and I use mouse-selected text. I see the mode as Visual after the mouse selection.
